# Make new array values from element value plus the previous element's value

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have array like this :

```
$array = array(1, 4, 8, 3, 7);
```

I want sum the value of array but first, I unshift the array like this :

```
<?php
 
$array = array(1, 4, 8, 3, 7);
 
array_unshift($array, 0);
array_pop($array);

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
   echo $val;
}

?>
```

then I want sum array first (`1, 4, 8, 3, 7`) with new array (`0, 1, 4, 8, 3`)
sum like 1 plus 0 and 4 plus 1 and 8 plus 4 etc

And I want the output is : `1, 5, 12, 11, 10`

Answer (score 3):

Just use [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map).
array_map allows you to use a custom function on multiple arrays at the same time

```
$array = array(1, 4, 8, 3, 7);

$others = $array;
array_unshift($others, 0);
array_pop($others);

function sumarray($v1,$v2){
    return $v1+$v2;
}

$res = array_map('sumarray', $array,$others);
print_r($res);
```

result like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop instead of foreach.

**Example**

```
$array = $array2 = array(1, 4, 8, 3, 7);

array_unshift($array, 0);
array_pop($array);

$array3 = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  $array3[] = $array[$i]+$array2[$i];
}

print_r($array3);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the popped value in a variable (`popped`) so you can use it later. Then you can use a regular for loop to loop over your array and add the `popped` value to the array once the loop is complete:

```
$array = array(1, 4, 8, 3, 7);

array_unshift($array, 0);
$popped = array_pop($array);

$result = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($array)-1; $i++) {
    $val1 = $array[$i];
    $val2 = $array[$i + 1];

    $result[] =  $val1 + $val2;
}

$result[] = end($array) + $popped; // add the last element with the popped value
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 12 [3] => 11 [4] => 10 )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pop or shift any elements and there is no need to create a copy of the input array.

As you iterate the input array, sum the current value with the previous value.  If there is no previous value, use zero.  This is exceedingly simple since your input is an indexed array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6JQXO))

```
$array = [1, 4, 8, 3, 7];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    $result[] = $value + ($array[$index - 1] ?? 0);
}

var_export($result);
// [1, 5, 12, 11, 10]
```

Functional style equivalent: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OAp76))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($v) {
            static $last = 0;
            $new = $v + $last;
            $last = $v;
            return $new;
        },
        $array
    )
);
```